# SWIFT 3.0 Azure Active Directory authentication example

Tags: swift, azure-active-directory

I'm currently developing an iOS app for a customer using Swift 3.0.This is my first app in Swift.

However my customer has asked me to restrict access to the app, using Azure Active Directory with Application Registration.

It is the only thing I need, to implement authentication using the app id of the app registered in the Azure Active Directory section of the Azure portal.

However I'm not finding any easy and working example of such an implementation. I've sought everywhere: microsoft, github, none of the examples I tried has worked.

Do you know of any really easy and working example that matches this requirements? I'm really desperate.

Answer (score 0):

[Here's](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-ios-swift-native-v2) a code sample that shows how to build a Swift app using the MSAL Objective-C library to integrate your app into Azure AD and call the Microsoft Graph API.

A few things worth nothing:

1. MSAL is in public preview.  It is supported for production environments, but the SDK may change before the General Availability.
2. The code sample (and MSAL) uses the Azure AD v2.0 endpoint.  This works best with an app registration at the [App Reg Portal](https://apps.dev.microsoft.com).  The app registration in the [Azure portal](https://portal.azure.com) is for the v1.0 endpoint and may not work using MSAL.

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks for the response! The point two is precisely one of the main problems with my integration. I've already got a test with Application registeres at the App Reg Portal and works sweet. But if I use an app id created at the Azure Portal (which is a Requisite from my customer) I allways obtain a Microsoft Graph Error (-4)

Comment: @SergioArmisén there's an [iOS v1 sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-ios), but it's using Objective-C.  Apple has some [documentation here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html) that helps use Objective-C components in a Swift app.

Answer (score 0):

Finally after some research I could make work which I think is the "official" Microsoft Active Directory Framework (ADAL for objectivec)

https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-objc

Even if the title ("objective-c") can be misleading, the project has a Samples Folder with an example in Swift. Tested and working. Maybe you will have to struggle with it a little bit, depending on your scenario.

[MSAL objective-c library iOS sample. Don't know how to configure it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48597765/msal-objective-c-library-ios-sample-dont-know-how-to-configure-it)